# Magento2 - custom color picker on product page

Tags: magento2, adminform

I would like to add a custom colour picker to an attribute that isn't a swatch colour. I have followed this tutorial for my attribute 'hue' and it is not working:

https://kiwicommerce.co.uk/blog/how-to-add-a-color-picker-in-product-edit-form-in-magento-2/

The swatch box shows but if I click on it then I get no pop up colour picker.

There is no error in the console or signs that anything is missing.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 mistakes in the color.html which I have found while following the link https://kiwicommerce.co.uk/blog/how-to-add-a-color-picker-in-product-edit-form-in-magento-2/

1. Call `initColorPicker()` in knockout `afterRender` binding
2. Put `data-role="color-picker"` on the div element

Below is the updated code for the `color.html` file

```
<div class="swatches-visual-col col-default" data-bind="afterRender: initColorPicker()">
 <div class="swatch_window" style="background: #000000"
    data-bind="
    style: {'background-color': value},
    'aria-describedby': noticeId,
    id: uid, disabled: disabled,
    attr: {title: placeholder},
    hasFocus: focused" data-role="color-picker">
 </div>
</div>
```

Putting it here so may be it can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize the color picker after the component has loaded,
you can do it by calling knockout afterRender binding

```
afterRender="initColorPicker()"
```

Hope it helps someone :)